# How to do this black/white background

Tags: photoshop-effects, photo-editing

[image]

I wanna know how to do this black background with little white details behind 'mata'

Comment: Hi @lucas and welcome to GDSE. I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. The background image isn't black and white as a whole, the "marble texture" behind the model is. But you talk about *little white details behind "mata"*. Are you talking about the texture of the fabric of the suit (which lies directly behind "mata")? Or perhaps the "marble texture" behind the model?

Comment: @Wolff, mata is the model hahaha, my bad. thanks

Comment: It's black marble with some copper sparkle. Because the model in front is well lit and there is some white part higher up the definition is not popping up.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see it with more light:

[image]

Only guesses are possible, it can originally have different colors, it can be multilayer item, it can be radically scaled to bigger size and it can also have JPG compression errors (=artefacts).

Its top edge seems to be sawn wood, so it can be a wood panel, but its vertical surface is covered with a texture photo which looks like it's wet stone or leather, the white spots are overexposed glitter of drops, the shadows suggest it's upside down. It's darkened to make it darker than the suit.

It has no perspective which fits the direction of the sawn top edge so it quite surely is an inserted texture without perspective insertion.

Yellowish splodges can be material or inserted transparent color or created by JPG process. JPG artefacts can be created in any step between image maker's lab and my screen. But they are non-disturbing without my heavy contrast and light increase.

I'm sorry, but only the maker of the composition knows how it's made.

But nothing prevents to attempt a fake. I have two layers. A stone texture and random grey dots. The dots are not well visible before the stone is darkened. The color of the dots is picked from your image.

[image]

After desaturating the stone it can be darkened:

[image]

Your texture is darker on the top. An adjustment layer with gradient layer mask fixes my version:

[image]

I guess my stone texture is a little sharper image than yours.

I made also other tests. Even Photoshop's Filter > Render > Clouds was nearly the same after applying Filter > Stylize > Emboss 1...2 px. After image is darkened this much the tolerance increases because fine details vanish.